# Remove the border of collapsible div within listview

Tags: html, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a problem of removing the border of a collapsible div within a li tag.
The demo is shown in http://jsfiddle.net/lightbringer/FsSmy/

```
<ul id="userstorylist" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
    <li id="draggable">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
            <h3>Userstory 1</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="draggable">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
            <h3>Userstory 2</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could anyone show me how to remove the border, I would like the items to stick together like normal listview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
    <li class="custom-li">
        <div class="custom-collapsible" data-name="1" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" data-corners="false">
            <h3>Userstory 1</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="custom-li">
        <div class="custom-collapsible" data-name="2" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" data-corners="false">
            <h3>Userstory 2</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with css styling:

```
.custom-li {
        padding: 0 !important;
        border-width: 0 !important;
}

.custom-collapsible {
    margin: 0 !important;   
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-width:0 !important;
}
```

This is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lightbringer/jWaEv/